# What is the consequence on purposefully lying on grad-school application (town of birth)

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application, academic-freedom, diversity

Sam was really really uncomfortable in disclosing their actual biographic data such as the town of birth (similar to Gaza). Sam felt that they will be discriminated.

There was no option to "prefer not to say", or "unknown".

I don't think such biographical info will have anything to do with academic qualifications.

Will Sam get caught and what is the common consequence of this practice?What is the consequence on purposely lying on grad-school application (town of birth)

Comment: In case this relates to grad school applications in the US or in the West more generally, I would recommend that you in addition ask: when applying to grad schools in the US, am I likely to be discriminated against based on my place of birth?

Comment: Is it common for a grad school application form to ask for the applicant's town of birth, other than perhaps on a detachable (i.e. concealed from admissions decision-makers) equal opportunities monitoring form?

Comment: @DanielHatton They all asked for the town of birth. Perhaps that will be on a biographic page, but there is no indicator of concealing. Perhaps we need an insider adcom member to tell us if that info is concealed.

Comment: @dodo In which countries is Sam applying?

Comment: In Germany you usually have to hand in a certified copy of your birth certificate for your contract (grad students are often employees).

Comment: @JFabianMeier where in Germany? I have never been asked for a birth certificate as a requisite for any employment in Germany (including as a doctoral student). ID card or passport is enough.

Comment: @wimi City of birth is usually on passport, though

Comment: I'd be concerned that, whether Sam knew it or not, there might be advantages to being from a different town.  If School likes to have students from every state but hasn't had enough applicants from Nebraska, then if Sam lies and says he's from Nebraska, he's committing fraud.  Or maybe someone endowed a scholarship for Nebraska born seekers of Ph.D.'s in Animal Husbandry.

Comment: @JFabianMeier When does that happen? You [have to do that in the US](https://www.uscis.gov/i-9) (passport, or proof of citizenship like birth certificate and ID), but that's done on your first day, well after acceptance.

Comment: As @JFabianMeier mentions, the truth will come out very soon as you will have to hand in the documents almost everywhere before you officially start. Also, why faking town and not country?

Comment: @wimi Maybe my information is outdated or depends on the Bundesland, but I worked at three different universities in Germany, and each university required me to hand in a copy of my birth certificate.

Comment: How would this situation come up?  A question like "town of birth" would have to have a free-form text entry field, I assume, since I can't imagine they would have something like a dropdown listing every possible town.  And if it's a free-form text box, then you could type "Decline to state".

Comment: @NateEldredge That's so smart! I will definitely look into that! Do you think there will be consequence of typing "Decline not state"? By the way, there are some applications that there is a dropdown list every possible state for each country.

Comment: I have no idea whether there are consequences, but surely they could not be more severe than the consequences of being caught lying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should strongly consider your motive for lying: if a person responsible for admissions is judging (not "evaluating," i.e they are forming a "like" or "dislike" opinion, rather than making educated guesses about what opportunities may have been available to you) your aptness for the program based on the place of birth written on the application, and has actionable (within their realm of being able to justify their admission recommendation or lack thereof) bias against your true place of birth, it is likely not an environment where you should spend the next several years.

In most countries, graduate schools will either offer you a stipend, or have such a high financial cost that you will need to take some kind of loan to cover tuition. In both of these cases, you will need to provide to the university (directly or indirectly) government-issued documentation, so the truth is likely to come out. Don't take your chances of lenience from a university holds a bias against you due to your place of birth.

Answer (score 11):

Any sort of dishonesty is frowned upon. It could be anything from nothing to expulsion and it is impossible to say. If you lie about one thing, are you going to lie about others in the future (muses the reviewer)?

You aren't responsible for where you were born. Nor are you responsible for what others do in the place you were born. It shouldn't be an issue, but lying is definitely a potential issue.

I doubt that an exception (say, Armenia v Azerbaijan) is the question here, where there is historical evidence of discrimination. But even in almost all such cases, academics tend to be better about such things than the general population. Even US v Russia at the moment isn't an issue for individuals.

Moreover if there is a place that would discriminate against you if the "only knew", then you don't want to go there. What happens when they learn of it.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I know plenty of Israelis who disagree vehemently with the direction the current government has gone (and been going for years). Israel isn't a homogeneous place.

Comment: @dodo To expand on Buffy's statement, it might take you from "worst case scenario = application rejected" to "worst case scenario = arrested".

Comment: @BryanKrause: Arrested for lying on a grad school application? Where might this happen?

Comment: @JochenGlueck The accusation wouldn't be lying on a grad school application, but that you're doing so for some nefarious reason, with fraudulent statements as evidence of guilt. Could more directly be fraud accusations if the difference in place of birth would qualify you for financial support that wouldn't otherwise be available.

Comment: @BryanKrause: Ok, I can see where you're coming from. Whether that's a plausible possibility in OP's situation does, of course, depend a lot on circumstances that we don't know. (Although I doubt that lying on a grad school application alone could be reasonable evidence for anything except for, well, lying on a grad school application. But then again, we don't know whether we are talking about a jurisdiction where courts sometimes decide on the judgement first and then hold the trial to find a reason...)

Comment: @JochenGlueck Yeah, I'm operating on the assumption that if someone is going to be treated unfairly for university admission based on their birthplace, other systems are also likely to treat them unfairly.

Comment: @JochenGlueck If you fill out 'Gaza' as your town of birth on an application for, say, a liberal arts college in the US, you can expect to receive a full scholarship regardless of any credentials. If you accept the scholarship and then it turns out you lied about your town of birth, you have committed fraud, a criminal offense.

Comment: @Servaes: Citation needed for your first sentence.

Comment: It is hard to imagine someone really getting arrested (in a democratic country) for lying about their town of birth in a way the OP asks (OP doesn't want to get more money, so they would presumably give a town of birth in the same "range" as Gaza (so if Gaza gives not more money, also a not-more-money-town). Does anyone have an example for anyone being arrested because of that? It's hard to believe

Answer (score 8):

You can typically read the consequences of lying on the admissions form itself. [Here's an example](https://www.slideshare.net/UNHGradSchool/university-of-new-haven-graduate-school-application-3196943).

> The information supplied on this application is complete and true to the best of my knowledge. No materials and supporting records submitted by me or on my behalf in connection with this application or my attendance will be released to anyone other than authorized university personnel without my consent. **It is understood that incorrect or falsified information will be grounds for disapproval of this application or dismissal from the university.** The undersigned agrees to pay all financial obligations if admitted to and attending the university, including assessed collection costs and any obligations incurred if financial aid is terminated, reduced, or postponed for any reason. ...

So the consequence is that they have legal grounds of declining Sam's application and/or dismissing Sam from the university if he has already been admitted. It doesn't mean they will, Sam could conceivably persuade them not to. But that will be the default reaction, and the onus will be on Sam to change that default (especially since if Sam lied about this, the odds of him lying about other aspects of his application goes up).

Answer (score 2):

If Sam isn't a citizen, lying is likely to attract grief from whoever checks up on visas — most countries do remarkably little data-matching, but if someone does bother that's a glaring red flag, especially as presumably they'd lie about which country they're from too.

If Sam is already at the institution in question for their undergrad, they'd be better off talking to a sympathetic senior academic and asking what information is even seen by those making admissions decisions.